# how to get specific types out of an structure

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to generate a type with the exact names of the RoutesPath.

So, the intention is to have a type with these values:

`// type RoutesPath --> 'institutions' | 'credentials' | 'token'`

But right now, I could only generate the generic type 'string' (`type RoutesPath --> string`).

Would that be possible?

```js
type RoutesPath = typeof routes[number]['children'][number]['path']

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/:token',
    component: PLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'institutions',
        name: 'display_information',
        component: InstitutionsView
      },
      {
        path: 'credentials',
        name: 'display_credentials',
        component: CredentialsView
      },
      {
        path: 'token',
        name: 'display_token',
        component: TokenView
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to achieve your goal using ***"const assertion"***

```
// type RoutesPath --> 'institutions' | 'credentials' | 'token'
```

***Check this :***

```
  type RoutesPath = typeof routes[number]["children"][number]["path"];

  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/:token",
      component: "x",
      children: [
        {
          path: "institutions",
          name: "display_information",
          component: "x",
        },
        {
          path: "credentials",
          name: "display_credentials",
          component: "x",
        },
        {
          path: "token",
          name: "display_token",
          component: "x",
        },
      ],
    },
  ] as const;
```

***Reason :***

If you don't use this assertion, the TS compiler will infer type  as string of "RoutesPath" , you can do const assertion and it will infer it as literal type.

Note:
You can do something like below if you don't want all to be literal types or readonly properties.

```
const example = {
  align: "left" as const,
  padding: 0,
};
```

So, inferred type will be :

```
 type example = {
     align : "left",
     padding : number,
   }
```

If you use it like below, everything will considered literal.

```
  const example = {
      align: "left",
      padding: 0,
    } as const;
```

The inferred type will be :

```
 type example = {
     align : "left",
     padding : 0,
   }
```

Hope it helps